# How can I play Day of the Tentacle?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, day-of-the-tentacle

I've got a modern PC running Windows 7 x64. How could I go about obtaining, and playing Day of the Tentacle?

Comment: @MPelletier: As long as you're not playing on ScummVM.  The original DOS version will let you play it but ScummVM won't since it will only work outside the game.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

First, you'll want to grab a copy of [ScummVM](http://www.scummvm.org/). DOTT (as well as [a bunch of other adventure games from that era](http://www.scummvm.org/compatibility/)) all run on a common game engine.  ScummVM is a modern implementation of that game engine which has been ported to pretty much [every platform under the sun](http://www.scummvm.org/downloads/).

Next, you'll need a copy of [Day of the Tentacle's data files](http://wiki.scummvm.org/index.php/Datafiles#Day_of_the_Tentacle). (`monster.sou`, `tentacle.000`, and `tentacle.001`) These come from the original game CD, which you'll need to obtain through whatever method you prefer. Once you have them, just click "Add Game" in ScummVM and browse to the directory they're found in.

Comment: This seems the best method, for any ScummVM based game. It also seems possible that the original install CD could be made to work using its own DOS-version of the ScummVM player, using DosBOX.

Comment: Just saw they have an Android version of ScummVM! I know what I'm doing when I get home :) Thanks, you get a "I helped someone relive their youth and all I got was this lousy t-shirt" t-shirt!

Comment: I also had a lot of fun playing the old classics on my Wii (Homebrew Channel + ScummVM needed for that) with the Wiimote on my TV.

Comment: @Alex: I used to play DoTT all the time on my WinPhone using ScummVM. Awesome! Though it works better with some games than others. Luckilly DoTT is completely playable.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if LucasArts planned on making a remake of DotT like it did the first two Monkey Island games, but due to a CEO change last year, it may not happen.  They released a bunch of games they didn't plan on remaking on Steam (Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade, Indiana Jones and the Fate of Atlantis, Loom, The Dig...)

Comment: I think DOSBox is a better alternative than ScummVM. If you don't want to deal with settings you can try frontends for DOSBox.

Answer (score 11):

You can play it on a modern PC and operating system using [ScummVM](http://www.scummvm.org/), this works for many, if not most adventures of that time.

Answer (score 8):

If you'd like, [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) also runs really well and is crossplatform too. I use it on my Linux machines to play Commander Keen, Dark Forces, Full Throttle, etc.

Answer (score 7):

There is also a [Remastered edition](http://store.steampowered.com/app/388210/) that was released in March 2016.

Comment: You were a few days early with this answer, but yes it was released on 2016 March 22.

Comment: On a side note: The Remastered Edition is available on Steam (Windows/OSX/Linux (soon)), GOG (Windows/OSX/Linux (soon)), and PSN (PS4).